# Hypothesis Testing Theory

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

Ok really simple, but I must be missing something in the theory.

If my $$H_0:p=.5$$
and $$H_1:p>.5$$

What happens if the sample data implies that $p<.5?$ Clearly my $H_0$ would be rejected, but then I would have to accept my $H_1$, which would contradict my known value of $p.$

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

A null hypothesis is usually state stated in the form of an equality. In the present example, we are testing

(1)$\qquad\qquad$  $H_{0}: p = 0.5$  against  $H_{1}: p > 0.5$.

In this case, even though the null hypothesis is stated as a simple equality, implicitly we are testing that

(2)$\qquad\qquad$  $H_{0}: p \leq 0.5$ against  $H_{1}: p > 0.5$.

Any test procedure that decides between $H_{0}$ and $H_{1}$ in (1), is also a reasonable test for (2).

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two hypotheses as above, you are sure that no other cases is possible. Sample data cannot implies smth about $p$ with complete confidence. Even if $\overline X<0.001$, this supports the null hypothesis.

But in practice, if you get sample values as in this example, this will be a reason to reconsider the grounds on which these two hypotheses were put forward.